# how to find the entity values size in dialog condition in Watson Conversation

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

I have an entity named "cities", and it has multiple values. I want to give a specific response if the user's text has more than 1 city in it. I tried to use this condition in dialog condition - @cities.values.size() > 1

But the above condition is not working, conversation tool is showing this is an incorrect entity operator.

Is there a way to check the size of values of an entity without using a context variable.

And this condition worked until today, and I see some changes to Conversation tool interface, SpEL stopped working in the dialog conditions. I hope the changes done to tool did not cause this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the condition you can use something like `entities.size()` to access the number of entities that have been found. If you only want to filter on `cities`, then you should try `entities['cities'].size()`. You can compare that value, so make it `entities['cities'].size()>1`.

[See here for several examples that I collected for working with variables in Watson Conversation](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/watson-conversation-variables).

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple.
Instead of using @cities.values.size() > 1 use @cities.size()>1